# magnitude of singular vectors

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Calculating the SVD $A = UST$ consists of finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $AA^T$ and $A^TA$. The eigenvectors of $A^TA$ make up the columns of V , the eigenvectors of $AA^T$  make up the columns of U.

I'm wondering if it matters what the magnitude of these eigenvectors are. Is it implied that these eigenvectors are unit norm?

Comment: Keep in mind that if $A^{T}A$ or $AA^{T}$ have repeated eigenvalues and eigenspaces of dimension higher than 1, then you can't simply take any collection of eigenvectors and use it in the SVD- they have to be properly matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's convention that the left and right singular vectors are normalized to be unit norm vectors.  You need some normalization or else the singular values in $\Sigma$ become indeterminate.

Comment: If v is a unit eigenvector then so is -v. In this case which should I pick?

Comment: You can use either plus or minus a singular vector in the SVD, but since the singular values are positive and $Av_{i}=\sigma_{i}u_{i}$, picking the sign of $u_{i}$ forces the sign of $v_{i}$ or vice versa.